# How to run a batch file during MyTestInitialize in Visual Studio Test Case

Tags: c#, unit-testing, batch-file, vs-unit-testing-framework

I want to run a batch file before executing each test case. The batch file will reset the things which every test case needs. So far I have tried the following:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "tools\build.bat";
    p.Start();
}
```

The above code throws a `Win32Exception` saying 'The system cannot find the file specified'. I believe I am setting the `FileName` correctly. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried setting the full path to see if it works then?

Comment: If I set the full path then it works. But, I am not able to set it dynamically..

Answer (score 0):

Your `FileName` is incorrect.  It may be that your path is incorrect (in which case supplying a fully qualified path will help), as it is, your string is being checked for escape sequences, so you would need to use:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"tools\build.bat"
```

to prevent the escape processing or

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "tools\\build.bat"
```

to supply a properly escaped `\` character.  Note, `\b` is a valid escape sequence, meaning backspace so would not result in a compile time error.

Based on your update, you don't actually want to use a relative path to your executable which is the default behaviour.  Instead, you want to generate a fully qualified path, dynamically.  The simplest way to do that is probably by getting the solution folder and doing a path relative to that.  So, given the following folder structure

```
c:\
   MySolution\
      MySolution.sln
   MyTestProject\
   tools\
      build.bat
```

You could use the following test initialize:

```
// Get solution folder (c:\MySolution)
string solutionDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(TestContext.TestDir));
Process p = new Process();
// Append relative path to solution folder
p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(solutionDir, @"tools\build.bat");
// At this point, FileName is "c:\MySolution\tools\build.bat"
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

If you don't already have it defined, you will need to add a property to your `TestClass` in order for the `TestContext` to be injected into your class.

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
```

You should also notice that I added a call to p.WaitForExit() into the initialize code, since it is unlikely that you will want your test execution to continue before your batch file completes.

```
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Ahh!! I mistyped it in my question. I am not getting any complie time error so I must have typed the "@" character in front of it. I am facing problem with setting the path dynamically..

Comment: \b is a valid escape sequence so you wouldn't get a compile time error...if the problem is setting it dynamically you're probably assuming the wrong working directory... You typically need to do the path relative to the binary (usually in your debug folder) so you'll need "..\.." or something to get up the folder where your tools folder is.

Comment: I tried it with the @ symbol and escaping character also like you said, but that didn't work

Comment: Replace the path with `@"cmd"` ...that should open a command window in whichever directory the binary is running in.  Work out a relative path from there to wherever your batch file is.

Comment: There must be some other way around for getting the path relative to the test execution folder. The path which you are asking is quite weird and I don't think so that would be a cleaner solution...